# Wrapping <li> with <ul> until next header in JQuery

Tags: javascript, jquery, list

How can I wrap `li` with `ul` until the next `h3`?

Here is my code:

```js
thisContent.find("li").each(function() {
  $(this).nextUntil("h3").andSelf();
}).wrap('<ul></ul>');
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<h3> Title 1 </h3>
<li> List 1 </li>
<li> List 2 </li>
<li> List 3 </li>
<li> List 4 </li>
<h3> Title 2 </h3>
<li> List 1 </li>
<li> List 2 </li>
<li> List 3 </li>
<li> List 4 </li>
```

This is what I expect it to be:

```html
<h3> Title 1 </h3>
<ul>
  <li> List 1 </li>
  <li> List 2 </li>
  <li> List 3 </li>
  <li> List 4 </li>
</ul>
<h3> Title 2 </h3>
<ul>
  <li> List 1 </li>
  <li> List 2 </li>
  <li> List 3 </li>
  <li> List 4 </li>
</ul>
```

Comment: But your former HTML markup isn't valid. It shouldn't be rendered, it could give unexpected result regarding how it is parsed by browser

Comment: @A.Wolff - Sorry, I forgot to mention that my current HTML structure is a result of a regex function..

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Use [wrapAll()](http://api.jquery.com/wrapall/).

Otherwise, you'll wrap each item individually.
You also need to start from `h3`, rather than `li`, because you're looking to wrap things between `h3`.

```
jQuery('h3').each(function(){
    $(this).nextUntil('h3').wrapAll('<ul></ul>')
})
```

```js
jQuery('h3').each(function() {
  $(this).nextUntil('h3').wrapAll('<ul class="potato"></ul>')
})
```

```css
.potato {
  background-color: yellow;
  border-radius: 1em;
  margin: 1em;
  padding: 1em 2em;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<h3> Title 1 </h3>
<li> List 1 </li>
<li> List 2 </li>
<li> List 3 </li>
<li> List 4 </li>
<h3> Title 2 </h3>
<li> List 1 </li>
<li> List 2 </li>
<li> List 3 </li>
<li> List 4 </li>
```

Comment: Wow! Thanks @Brachamul for answering my question!

Comment: My pleasure sir. I believe this was my first accepted answer :)